# How to add a subtotal column in Datatables

Tags: datatables

[My last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877813/total-of-multiple-columns-using-datatables-footer-callback) was related to the sum of columns (vertically) and now I need to sum the values of the columns (horizontally)

What I've tried:

I've tried iterating all columns `table.columns().data()` and sum the values but I do not know how to "inject" the result of the sum in the last column.

Desired result:

[image]

Sub Total is the result of: `3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12`

[LIVE JS BIN](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your JS code with your old code. You can also see it from [here](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/20/edit)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    var DT1 = $('#example').DataTable({

        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0,
        }],
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
        "language": {
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ Projects",
            "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 Projects",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total Projects)"
        },
        "pagingType": "numbers",
        dom: 'rtip',
        initComplete: function(settings, json) {
            // calculate the sum when table is first created:
            doSum();
        }
    });

    $('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
        // re-calculate the sum whenever the table is re-displayed:
        doSum();
    });
    $(".selectAll").on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            DT1.rows().select();
        } else {
            DT1.rows().deselect();
        }
    });

    // This provides the sum of all records:
    function doSum() {
        // get the DataTables API object:
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        // set up the initial (unsummed) data array for the footer row:
        var totals = ['', 'Total:', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        // iterate all rows - use table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).data()
        // if you want to sum only filtered (visible) rows:
        totals = table.rows().data()
            // sum the amounts:
            .reduce(function(sum, record) {
                for (let i = 2; i <= 12; i++) {
                    sum[i] = sum[i] + numberFromString(record[i]);
                }
                return sum;
            }, totals);
        // place the sum in the relevant footer cell:
        for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            var column = table.column(i);
            $(column.footer()).html(formatNumber(totals[i]));
        }


        $('#example > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
            var rowSum = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (j >= 2) {
                    var tdCellValue = numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
                    rowSum = rowSum + tdCellValue;
                }
                if (j >= 11) {
                    tr.cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
                }
            }
        });

        $('#example > tfoot  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
            var rowSum = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (j >= 2) {
                    var tdCellValue = numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
                    rowSum = rowSum + tdCellValue;
                }
                if (j >= 11) {
                    tr.cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function numberFromString(s) {
        return typeof s === 'string' ?
            s.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
            typeof s === 'number' ?
            s : 0;
    }

    function formatNumber(n) {
        return n.toLocaleString(); // or whatever you prefer here
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why is there an extra `0000000002`?

Comment: @Cheknov can you check it once again?
row1 sum value, 1004156 = (100013 +100546+ 100444 +100222+ 100466+ 100789+ 100122+ 100333+ 100999+ 
100222)=1004156 
row2 sum value, 1000000 = (100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 +100000 )
row3 sum value, 2004156 = (200013 + 200546 +200444 +200222 +200466 +200789 +200122 +200333 +200999 +200222 )